# Icon to clicked twice when focus inside input box

Tags: javascript

I have a table with pagination. There are two actions

1. On a row click next row expand or collapse.
2. Table having action column which having icon View to navigate to other view page.

Issue:

When the focus is inside input box of pagination, and I clicked on view icon, the first click did not work then I click again on view icon again then it works.

I am working in web JavaScript project.

Comment: Kindly any one have face similar problem

Comment: Give a minimal verifiable and complete code sample to debug